# eclipse indigo cannot create new server jboss 5.1

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, application-server

I have installed Eclipse EE Indigo and I want to create a new instance of Jboss server, version 5.1, but this option is not available. The latest version of Jboss server I can create is 5.0.

Do I need to install something within Eclipse in order to be able to create a Jboss 5.1 server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have installed Eclipse EE Indigo and I want to create a new instance of Jboss server, version 5.1, but this option is not available. The latest version of Jboss server I can create is 5.1.

So...you want to create a server instance for version 5.1, but the latest version you can create is 5.1?  That doesn't make any sense.  Do you really mean 7.1?

> Do I need to install something within Eclipse in order to be able to create a Jboss 5.1 server?

Yes, you need to install the JBoss Tools in Eclipse.

In Eclipse (Indigo) click on "Help" -> "Install New Software", and add this URL as a repository: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/

If I remember right, the one you're going to need is the "Web and Java EE Development."  Or "Select All" just to make sure.

That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry for the mistake with the server version.

Comment: Hey no worries, I just hope it helped you get it all figured out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install JBossAS Tools.

Click on "Help" --> "Eclipse Marketplace ..." --> In "Find" input field type "jboss" --> Click on "Go"

First or second should be JBoss Tools (Juno) or (Indigo) depending on what version you use.

Click on "Install"

Don't install everything, you just need "JBossAS Tools".

Accept the licence agreement. You might get asked to trust the unsigned content or something similar. After few minutes, you should be asked if you want to restart Eclipse, do that.

And voila, you have new group of servers under "JBoss Community".

You can create JBoss 5.1.0.GA or JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final with these tools.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To install JBossAS Tools, you could follow this steps also.

- Go to the Server tabs
- After that, add the new server
- And in the new window, click in the *"Download additional server adapters"*
- Select **JBossAs**, install  and restart you eclipse.